# How to get the most recent user's data in firebase using javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

From this image below:

How can I get the childrens of the **userResult** from the most recent user (sample user rricarde)?
From this image below I need to get the most recent user data and all the most recent answer of it and append to HTML table data **class="expert-response"**

[image]

Sample output:
Data get from the recent user: rricarde

```
<table  id="results">
  <tr>
    <th>Expert response</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="expert-response"> Somewhat agree</span></td>
<!--Statement01 most recent answer -->
    <td><span class="expert-response">Yes, usually</span></td> 
<!--Statement02 most recent answer -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you using firebase keys, all firebase key are generated with timestamp in it, so it's presorted already, the last one will be the last input, however if you want to know how to sort in firebase .

```html
firebase.database().ref(endpoint)
  .orderByChild('timestamp')
  .on('value', function(snapshot){
    //do something here
  })
```

[orderbychild](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#orderByChild)

there's much more it can do, you can read the api.
For your second question, I think you should make a bit more effort on learning how to render firebase content in html.